# First time JUnit user: Why eclipse always shows error (Red indicator)

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

This is my first time doing/learning unit testing using JUnit eclipse.

- I've added `JUnit 4.12.jar` via *right clicking* on the project

Now : I've 2 classes:

```
public class Calculate {
    public int sum(int var1, int var2) {
        System.out.println("Adding values: " + var1 + " + " + var2);
        return var1 + var2;
    }
}
```

---

```
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CalculateTest {
    Calculate calculation = new Calculate();
    int sum = calculation.sum(2, 5);
    int testSum = 7;

    @Test
    public void testSum() {
        System.out.println("@Test sum(): " + sum + " = " + testSum);
        assertEquals(sum, testSum);
    }
}
```

Finally, every time (Every examples) I right click at, then

**CalculateTest.java->Run as->JUnit Test**

It shows me this instead:

[image]

While it should be something like this :

[image]

How to do it in the right way?

Comment: what does the error read? (you can hover/click on that and check)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `hamcrest 1.3` library to your project and it should work fine !

Comment: that shouldn't be required.

Comment: doesn't mean to be a generic solution unless you can point to the cause of problem.

Comment: I may be wrong, but newest version of JUnit doesn't seem to include hamcrest so you need to add it by yourself.

Comment: ...only if you are using something specific to it. By the way unless the OP states what the error is, lets not speculate.

Answer (score 1):

The following (pretty much a copy of what you did) runs with no errors:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CalculateTest {

    Calculate calculation = new Calculate();
    int sum = calculation.sum(2, 5);
    int testSum = 7;

    @Test
    public void testSum() {
        System.out.println("@Test sum(): " + sum + " = " + testSum);
        assertEquals(sum, testSum);
    }

    public class Calculate {
        public int sum(int var1, int var2) {
            System.out.println("Adding values: " + var1 + " + " + var2);
            return var1 + var2;
        }
    }
}
```

If you run it with no errors: find the difference.

If it produces errors, what are they ?